# How to change the yellow square background when press down on a button in a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, coding-style

See the yellow background effect by click an icon on your android's main app menu.

Is there any way to change the style, change it to a transparent background or some other styles that looks better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {              
        int c = Color.BLUE;
        gridview.getChildAt(arg2).setBackgroundColor(c);    
    }});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple..add this to the gridview tag

android:listSelector="#00000000"

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear with your requirement but yes you can create style in values folder.
file name `style.xml`

```
<resources>
    <style name="ReviewScreenKbbNameStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">#2F2E86</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12dip</item>
    </style> 
</resources>
```

and in your layout you can use your style like this or you can use your style in your program

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/mid_bot_left_kbb_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:text="@string/kbb_name"
    style="@style/ReviewScreenKbbNameStyle"/>
```